# What anime, fanart, or random art is this girl with a gun from?

Tags: soul-worker-online

I don't know which anime/manga/fanart this is, but if you could help me, thanks in advance!

[image]

<sup>Original link: http://www.imgbase.info/images/safe-wallpapers/anime/anime_girls/35522_anime_girls_anime_girl_with_gun.jpg</sup>

Answer (score 10):

[image: Artwork]

<sub>Image from shuushuu. Click to enlarge!</sub>

This image is from the video game **Soul Worker Online**. Your image is mirrord and the *Soulworker Lion Games* watermark is removed.

[image: Artwork]

> Soul Worker is an anime action MMORPG which takes place in the
>   Cloudrealm, a now vacant city which only harbors the psychics and a
>   horde of monsters. Players will learn about the fate of the city and
>   the reason for the disappearance of all inhabitants through the course
>   of the game, as well as possibly finding a way to reverse this
>   catastrophe.

<sub>Image from [liongames](http://www.liongames.co.kr/Front/?url=game). Information from [freemmostation](http://www.freemmostation.com/games/soul-worker/).</sub>

Comment: I think this should nail it: http://mmoculture.com/2014/03/soul-worker-china-server-announcement-horrifies-the-gamers/